# Change checkbox state

Tags: checkbox, react-native

I am trying to create a ListView with multiple rows. Each row have a checkbox + text.
This is my implementation of a ListView:

```
class ListExample extends Component {

  constructor() {
      super();
      const ds = new ListView.DataSource({rowHasChanged: (r1, r2) => r1 !== r2});
      this.state = {
        dataSource: ds.cloneWithRows(["hey1", "hey2", "hey3", "hey4"]),
      };
    }

    render() {
      return (
        <ListView
          dataSource={this.state.dataSource}
          renderRow={(data) => <Row data={data} />}
        />
      );
    }
}
export default ListExample;
```

This is my implementation of a row:

```
import React from 'react';
import { CheckBox } from 'native-base';
import { View, Text, StyleSheet} from 'react-native';

const Row = (props) => (
  <View style={styles.container}>
    <CheckBox onPress={props.onPress} checked={false} />
    <Text style={styles.text}>
      { props.data }
    </Text>
  </View>
);
export { Row };
```

Now I need create behavior on the checkbox. My goal is when a person click on the checkbox the box change the state to checked.

How can I do that ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the state of your Row component:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { CheckBox } from 'native-base';
import { View, Text, StyleSheet} from 'react-native';

class Row extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { checked: false };
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <CheckBox
          onPress={() => this.setState({
            checked: !this.state.checked
          })}
          checked={this.state.checked}
        />
        <Text style={styles.text}>
          { props.data }
        </Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

export default Row;
```

Comment: I receive this error "Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. Check the render method of `StaticRenderer`." @guitoof

Comment: I change to "export { Row };" and now works. Thank you!

Comment: Oh yeah sorry I tested it locally with the export default and forgot to change it back in my answer.
Glad it helped ;) Enjoy React Native !